# Returning added rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that displays data from an `SQL table`.  It is using `sqldependency` so that an alert is made when the data changes, and the `DataGridView` immediately displays the updated data.  New rows will be added to this table regularly, and when this happens I want to take only those new rows from the first data grid and populate a separate `DataGridView`.

I've experimented a bit with `RowAdded event`, but it hasn't been entirely straightforward because it creates an alert for every row in the table whenever the grid view is updated by `sqldependency`.

Does anyone have experience doing something similar?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Could you show us some code on what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the first DataGridView with all the rows *Grid A* and the DataGridView that shows only new rows *Grid B*. Don't define the contents of Grid B by observing changes to Grid A. Instead, create your own definition of what a "new row" is. One easy way to do this is to make a copy of the contents of Grid A during every update (in the OnChange event of our SqlDependency object). Then, on the next update you'll be able to select rows into the "new rows" DataSet.

Here's the pseudo-code for the OnChange handler for your SqlDependency object (this should be watching the SqlCommand that fills Grid A):

1. Run a SqlCommand that selects rows from the Grid A datasource with an NOT IN clause that excludes rows with ID in a 2nd table called *LastUpdate* (see step 2). This will be the data source for Grid B
2. Run a SqlCommand that copies all rows of the Grid A data source to the LastUpdate table. It may be easiest to just delete the contents of LastUpdate first, then run a statement of the form: `INSERT INTO LastUpdate(ID) SELECT ID FROM table_x`
3. Update the Grid A normally

The point I want to emphasize is that this update strategy creates an effective separation between data queries and the UI. In other words, the data that drives Grid B does not in any way depend on Grid A. If you stick with this principle, you should wind up with a much more maintainable application.